# Scraping Google Images with Scrapy / Splash - Getting redirected

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping, splash-screen

I am attempting to scrape the result of a reverse image searching using Google Images.

My start URL is https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=DIRECT_IMAGE_URL, which works as intended in the browser.

However, when I attempt to scrape it via Scrapy, the request is redirected 3 times, as shown;

[image: Image reverse search redirects]

with the resulting webpage looking like

[image: Google search result]

instead of the results page. Here's my Scrapy settings.py

```
    SPLASH_URL = 'http://splash:8050'
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
     SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
      }
     DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
      HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
      REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES = 2
      HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
```

I have considered;

1. Lack of Javascript - so I used Splash to render the page
2. Cookies - I think it's working?
3. Setting maximum redirects - Didn't work

Here's my call to SplashRequest;

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, meta={
        'cookiejar': i,
        'wait': 0.5,
        'splash': {
          'args': {
              'html': 1,
              'png': 1,
          },
          'splash_headers': {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
          }       # optional; a dict with headers sent to Splash
      }
```

Any idea what's causing the 3 redirects? The first redirect is necessary for the result, but the 2nd and 3rd ones aren't and give me the wrong page.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out! My error was in the User-Agent. I thought I was setting the User-Agent, but I was in fact setting the headers for the *request that is sent to Splash*, not the request that is actually sent to the page I want to scrape.

In order to get this working, I changed

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, meta={
            'cookiejar': i,
            'wait': 0.5,
            'splash': {
              'args': {
                  'html': 1,
                  'png': 1,
              },
              'splash_headers': {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
              }       # optional; a dict with headers sent to Splash
          }
        })
```

to

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, meta={
            'cookiejar': i,
            'wait': 0.5,
            'splash': {
              'args': {
                  'html': 1,
                  'png': 1,
              }
          },
        }, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I have a somewhat similar project in line, that is going to help me a lot.